# Powershell - CSV - Header - Save

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm reading a fixed-width file with 4000 rows though substrings, and assigning each substring to a header in a csv. But I'm not sure how to save the csv.

An example row am reading:

```
$line = ABC       7112123207/24/16Smith                              Timpson                            Head Coach                                                            412-222-0000        00011848660    ELl CAAN HIGH SCHOOL                  325 N Peal AVE.                   Smith                         Timpson                       Head Coach                              COLORADO CITY            AZ 86021       01             FALL      MALE      07/29/16EQ15031                  1977904        BUDDY'S ALL STARS INC.                  BUDDY ALL STARS                                                                                                                             N                 V12V70R16                                1.00V12V70R16
```

I've the csv with the headers.

```
$csvheaders = import-csv temp.csv 

foreach ($Line in (Get-Content $FILE.FullName))
{     
    foreach($csh in $csvheaders)
    {
        $csh.GROUP = $line.Substring(0,10).Trim() 
        $csh.NUMBER = $line.Substring(10,8).Trim()        
        $csh.DATE=$line.Substring(18,8).Trim()
        $csh.CONTACT_FIRST=$line.Substring(26,35).Trim()
        $csh.CONTACT_LAST=$line.Substring(61,35).Trim()
    }
}
```

I would need the csv output as:

```
Group      Number     Date       Contact_First   Contact_Last 
ABC        71121232   07/24/16   Smith           Timpson
```

Comment: [Export-Csv](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849932.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Export-Csv](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113299) cmdlet:

```
Get-Content $FILE.FullName | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Group = $_.Substring(0,10).Trim()   
        Number = $_.Substring(10,8).Trim()  
        Date = $_.Substring(18,8).Trim()
        Contact_First = $_.Substring(26,35).Trim()
        Contact_Last = $_.Substring(61,35).Trim()
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'Your_Output_Path.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

**Note:** You probably need to specify a tab delimiter for the `Export-Csv` cmdlet.

Comment: What should I pipe to the Export-csv? Another caveat is that I cannot use a hash table to add rows to csv as I've duplicate keys.

Comment: Just show us your files (with only a few examples) and the output you expect. Then we can help you.

Comment: Please look at my updated answer and consider accepting it ;-)

Comment: This won't work as I mentioned earlier that duplicate keys are not allowed in hash literals

Comment: The $line in the question is an extract and has more values, one of which is empty. So it is considered a null object and fails as: Duplicate keys '' are not allowed in hash literals.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120253/discussion-between-mokshyam-and-martin-brandl).

Comment: So, do you have a CSV file already and you just want to parse this file and add additional content to the existing CSV? If so, import the existing CSV to a variable, use Martin's code (minus the Export-CSV part) to parse the text file, add the new objects to the existing (array) variable representing the imported CSV, and then export the combined results out with Export-CSV. Or am I missing something?